# Maven update doesn't work after installing artifact, only after deploy

Tags: maven-3

I really don't get it, I have a multimodule project (snapshots) and I'm using Nexus repo manager. If I make changes to projectB and `$mvn install` it, then projectA still uses the old dependency when being built.

No matter if I do `$mvn -o compile` or `$mvn -U compile`, it still has the old dependency on classpath.

If I deploy projectB `$mvn deploy`, projectA still gets the old dependency on classpath
unless I go `$mvn -U compile`, then fresh snapshot projectB dependency is served on classpath of projectA when being built. This works as expected.

BUT

`$mvn install` simply doesn't allow me to use the installed artifact version from outside, no matter what. I always have to `deploy` it and run `$mvn -U compile` for others to get the fresh dependency.

Could please anybody explain to me, why this happens ? Clearly  `maven install` and `update` should work, but it requires `deploy`. What the hell ?

Comment: Have you changed the localRepository location via [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) or, something else to make your local m2 repo unusable?

Comment: yeah I'm using non-default local repository location.

Comment: mvn probably face some problem when updating it. Make sure you have access rights. And, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mvn install` installs the built jars to the local repo at ~/m2/repository/. When it comes to snapshots, `mvn install` replaces the old snapshot with the new one.

It seems there's an issue with your local repo. So, I suggest deleting the current snapshots from the local repo, and try again. In the worst case, delete the entire ~/.m2 repo and try again.

Right now you are doing it the hard way by uploading your artifacts to the remote and repo (via `mvn deploy`), and downloading again with `mvn -U compile`.

Based on the comments - it seems to be a bug in the maven-install-plugin. Newest version is maven-install-plugin-2.3.1. Set the plugin explicitly in your pom.

Comment: I'm using maven for 3 years, I really checked on this. I suppose that there would be error logs in -X debug mode when access rights were not ok. Moreover they are correctly set... Guys on irc channel said they encountered this as well, but they didn't find the reason.

Comment: OK. Well then, have you checked the timestamp of the snapshot in the local repo before and after running `mvn install` on projectB? It will clearly shows whether your snapshot on the local repo got updated! Those important bits wasn't in the question.

Comment: You know what happens ? It just sometimes doesn't get physically stored on FileSystem when installing and sometimes it does... Not access rights related. Sometimes after install it's just not there. I'm using strictly console, I do not source any other settings.xml, so it must be some maven bug or something. I'm sure it is not installed to any other location and -X debug mode doesn't show anything... weird

Comment: Well, for me, it shows where the jar gets installed. Something like "Installing /home/kasun/maven-sample-project-1/target/utils-1.jar to /home/kasun/.m2/repository/utils/1/utils-1.jar". It shows even without -X. Yours not?

Comment: May be the issue is related to maven-install-plugin. What version do you have? Newest version is maven-install-plugin-2.3.1. Set is explicitly in your pom, and try. May be this issue has been already solved!